# Overwrite/override method signature in TypeScript interface

Tags: typescript

In this particular example, I'm extending the `Array<T>` interface like so:

```
interface BetterArray<T> extends Array<T> {
    push(this: BetterArray<T>, value: T): this;
}
```

*Note for reference - `Array<T>.push` is implemented like this*

```
interface Array<T> {
    push(...items: T[]): number;
}
```

But I get the following compile-time error:

> Interface 'BetterArray' incorrectly extends interface 'T[]'.
>   Types of property 'push' are incompatible.
>       Type '(this: BetterArray, value: T) => this' is not assignable to type '(...items: T[]) => number'.
>         Type 'this' is not assignable to type 'number'.
>           Type 'BetterArray' is not assignable to type 'number'.

Is there any way I can forcibly instruct TypeScript that I want to overwrite push on my interface *(like [member hiding in C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/435f1dw2.aspx))*?

**Note - I'm using TypeScript 2.0**

Further reading - it appears that this is purely down to return type - basically I want to enforce by interface, a new return type...

```
interface A {
    fn(): number;
}

interface B extends A {
    fn(): this;
}
```

> Interface 'B' incorrectly extends interface 'A'.   Types of property
>   'fn' are incompatible.
>       Type '() => this' is not assignable to type '() => number'.
>         Type 'this' is not assignable to type 'number'.
>           Type 'B' is not assignable to type 'number'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to add the original signature of `Array.push`:

```
interface BetterArray<T> extends Array<T> {
    push(...items: T[]): number;
    push(this: BetterArray<T>, value: T): this;
}
```

The problem with what you want to do though is that if `this` is a `BetterArray` then you can not return `this`, for exampl:

```
class BetterArrayClass<T> extends Array<T> {
    push(...items: T[]): number;
    push(this: BetterArrayClass<T>, value: T): this;
    push(this: BetterArrayClass<T>, ...items: T[]): number | this {
        return this;
    }
}
```

Errors with:

> Type 'BetterArrayClass' is not assignable to type 'number | this'.
>   Type 'BetterArrayClass' is not assignable to type 'this'.
>   this: BetterArrayClass

The reason for that can be seen in this simpler example:

```
class A {
    fn(this: A, num: number): this {
        return this; // Error: Type 'A' is not assignable to type 'this'. this: A
    }
}

class B extends A {
    fn(num: number): this {
        if (num < 0) {
            return super.fn(num);
        }
        return this;
    }
}
```

If in `B.fn` we're calling `super.fn` then the `this` is not `A` but `B`, and in any case we want to return the instance of `B`.
Which is not what `A.fn` describes.

Comment: Thanks very much for this, however it's a little more complicated when it comes down to not even using classes, and having to delve a little deeper into JS, because TypeScript simply isn't capable of emiting the construct I'm building. With regards to this, I found another solution, based on yours. See my solution

Comment: I wonder what's this construct of yours that typescript isn't able to cope with

Comment: Well it needs a constructor that can do this: new <T extends {}>(n?: T): T & Q ...and TypeScript cries like a baby when I tried to do that with a class!

Comment: Can you edit your question again and explain better what you're trying to do? It seems that you want to override the `Array.push` method and return the array instance instead of the number that is usually returned. If that's the case, then do you do that for all arrays (override the prototype) or do you construct new instances of this extended array? and if so how?

Answer (score 1):

As per [nitzan tomer's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/942852/nitzan-tomer) | [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39923895/1033686)

You just need to add the original signature of Array.push:

```
interface BetterArray<T> extends Array<T> {
    push(...items: T[]): number;
    push(this: BetterArray<T>, value: T): this;
}
```

Using the `never` type seems to work for this. Intellisense picks up that `never`, "**never**" returns, so doesn't bother showing you the method signature *(neat)*

```
interface BetterArray<T> extends Array<T> {
    push(...items: T[]): never;
    push(this: BetterArray<T>, value: T): this;
}
```

Comment: Strange...but it only seems to remove the "never" method sig beyond the first push(...) in the chain.

Comment: While using `never` gets you this desired intellisense effect, it's a misuse of the feature and might get you into trouble later on in the future as it "lies" about the actual implementation.

Comment: @NitzanTomer can't I just interpret this as "this implementation will 'NEVER' happen"? -cheeky emoji-

Comment: You can. But you're overriding the actual implementation which returns a number. That might bite you (or someone else who's using your code) later in the future.