# Overriding a generic method in typescript

Tags: typescript

I am trying to create one base class `AbstractQuery` and inherit it by child classes and then override some of its methods.

```js
class AbstractQuery {
    public before<A, S>(context: Context<A>, args: A, source?: S): Promise<A> {
        return Promise.resolve(args);
    }
}
```

Now I would like to override above `AbstractQuery::before` method in my child class:

```js
class FindBookByIdQuery extends AbstractQuery {
    public before(context: Context<arguments.ID>, args: arguments.ID): Promise<arguments.ID> {
        this.log.debug('hook before args', args);
        return Promise.resolve(args);
    }
}
```

But I am getting error:

> [ts]
>   Property 'before' in type 'FindBookByIdQuery' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'AbstractQuery'.
>     Type '(context: Context, args: ID) => Promise' is not assignable to type '(context: Context, args: A, source?: S) => Promise'.
>       Types of parameters 'context' and 'context' are incompatible.
>         Type 'Context' is not assignable to type 'Context'.
>           Type 'A' is not assignable to type 'ID'. [2416]

Comment: Did you get any useful insights on this?

Comment: Yes, I solved it with the help of following link https://stackoverflow.com/a/39923895/9709887

Answer (score 4):

TypeScript is right to point out the mistake. In `AbstractQuery`, the context used by the `before` method is bound with its type parameter. However, in `FindBookByIdQuery` not such relation exists.

If you want to allow `before` to have variadic behavior, overload its definition. Consider this example:

```
declare abstract class Foo<T> {
    before<U>(context: U): Promise<U>;
    before(context: T): Promise<T>
}

declare class Bar<T> extends Foo<T> {
    before(context: T): Promise<T>
}
```

Here, `before` can be generic (first overload) or depend on some other type. In this example. this *other type* is the type parameter of the class itself.

Comment: Thanks for answering. My `AbstractQuery` class has other functions too which need not to be overridden, so it can not be pure `abstract` class! The compiler is not complaining about the variadic behavior, I guess, its complaining about "Type 'A' is not assignable to type 'ID'" not sure how to fix this?